# C++ как лучше передавать объекты?

Tags: c++, c, указатели, контейнеры, ссылка

Как лучше всего передавать любые объекты из контейнеров в функцию например из вектора, указателем на объект или по ссылке на него? Как в плане скорости, так и в плане удобства.

Comment: С точки зрения размера и скорости - одинаково. Хотя если объект маленький, например `int`, то проще передать копию. А вот с точки зрения удобства и безопасности - лучше ссылка. Указатель можно переприсвоить, его надо явно разыменовывать. Ссылка удобнее в работе. А вообще это зависит от задачи. Если вам в функции нужна копия объекта - то всё равно придется эту копию делать.

Comment: Ссылка по функциональности это просто константный указатель `&` == `* const` с урезанными правами. Ссылка не может ссылаться на объект с нулевым указателем **nullptr**. У ссылки нельзя брать её адрес. Адрес возвращается самого объекта. Если вам не нужны фишки указателей, то можно пользоваться ссылками.

Comment: @DmitryK а если объект в контейнере, в std vector каком-нибудь, то тоже ссылка предпочтительней? Просто vector может быть в какой-то момент быть передислоцирован и все развалится

Comment: Если вектор реаллоцирует память, то и указатель станет невалидным. Даже если вектор не реаллоцировал память, а просто вставлен элемент до того, на который у вас ссылка/указатель/итератор, то ваш итератор станет невалидным. Т.к. вектор просто перенесет элементы на новое место (сдвинет). Это особенности работы контейнеров, о которых нужно читать в помощи по контейнерам. Тут только передача копии поможет. Но это не имеет никакого отношения к удобству работы с ссылками/указателями.

Comment: Не о том думаете. Способ передачи в функцию должен зависеть от смысла функции, а не от способа размещения объекта. Хорошая функция д.б. написана так, чтобы ее можно было использовать независимо от контейнера

Answer (score -1):

По ссылке или по указателю. Передача по значению – это всегда передача копии самого объекта, на копирование же может тратиться много времени, в лучшем случае оно равно времени передачи по ссылке. Если объект надо защитить от изменения внутри функции, то по константной ссылке или по указателю на константу. И только если требуется изменение параметра внутри функции при одновременной защите оригинального объекта от изменения внутри функции, то остаётся единственный вариант – передача по значению. Главным различием между передачей по ссылке и по указателю должно быть синтаксическое, а получаемый код должен быть эквивалентен (но не обязан быть идентичен, так как реализация ссылки отдана на откуп разработчикам компиляторов, но вести себя ссылка обязана как указатель, завёрнутый в нечто, гарантирующее разыменование по умолчанию при каждом обращении). Если это не так, то что-то перекосячил разработчик компилятора.

Comment: "*то остаётся единственный вариант – передача по значению*" — а вариант создания копии внутри функции вы не рассматриваете принципиально?

Comment: А вариант передачи параметра по значению в функцию, только вызывающую другую функцию, только вызывающую другую функцию, Вы почему не рассматриваете?

Comment: А если серьёзно, то я обсуждаю написание программ, а не привидение их в состояние алкогольного опьянения, поэтому и не рассматриваю фактическую передачу по значению при формальной передаче по ссылке и фактическую передачу по значению при формальной передаче по ссылке, смотрю сразу в самый конец процесса передачи.

Comment: [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision): передача по значению **не всегда** передача копии.

Comment: Серьёзно? А ничего, что это ПО УСЛОВИЮ передача копии?